# Have to delete and re add my server when I pull code from git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat

I have a Java project I am working on with some other people. We are using GIT as our CMS and Eclipse as our IDE. Every time one of us pushes code, and the other one pulls it we get errors in our JSP's and have to delete our tomcat server completely from eclipse, then re-add it. After adding it again, we have to go to the project properties, go to Java Facets and add the server as a runtime. This is a quick process but annoying. Is there anything we can add in the .gitignore or something to avoid this?

Comment: what kind of errors you are getting? in what kind of files? any files other than code files??

Comment: Just code files yes. It's a J2EE project and it's as if the files are not being associated with the server anymore. So I have to re-add my server and the errors in the code go away.

Comment: If all files are code files. There's nothing to do with .gitignore. So as you are explaining do you get this only when you pulling newly created files?

Comment: It's once the code has been run on my partners computer and then pushed.

Comment: then there should be another file gets changed. a config file??

Answer (score 0):

The errors are most probably happening due to a conflict between the local settings of the server. 
To stop that, instead of adding all changes, add only the files you purposefully created. Identify the local settings files, files created by the IDE and put them in .gitignore.